# Replace a substring between two substrings

Tags: python, regex

How can I replace a substring between `page1/` and `_type-A` with `222.6` in the below-provided `l` string?

```
l = 'https://homepage.com/home/page1/222.6 a_type-A/go'
replace_with = '222.6'
```

Expected result:

```
https://homepage.com/home/page1/222.6_type-A/go
```

I tried:

```
import re
re.sub('page1/.*?_type-A','',l, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

But it also removes `page1/` and `_type-A`.

Comment: Try: `re.sub('(?<=page1/).*?(?=_type-A)', replace_with, l)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` like this:

```py
import re

l = 'https://homepage.com/home/page1/222.6 a_type-A/go'
replace_with = '222.6'

print (re.sub(r'(?<=page1/).*?(?=_type-A)', replace_with, l))
```

**Output:**

```bash
https://homepage.com/home/page1/222.6_type-A/go
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ulOiD/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<=page1/)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have `page1/` at previous position
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any string (lazy)
- `(?=_type-A)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `_type-A` at next position

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
import re
l = 'https://'+'homepage.com/home/page1/222.6 a_type-A/go'
replace_with = '222.6'
print (re.sub('(page1/).*?(_type-A)',fr'\g<1>{replace_with}\2',l, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Output: `https://homepage.com/home/page1/222.6_type-A/go`

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/gRwZdC)

Note you used an empty string as the replacement argument. In the above snippet, the parts before and after `.*?` are *captured* and `\g<1>` refers to the first group value, and `\2` refers to the second group value from the replacement pattern. The unambiguous backreference form (`\g<X>`) is used to avoid backreference issues since there is a digit right after the backreference.

Since the replacement pattern contains no backslashes, there is no need preprocessing (escaping) anything in it.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import re

l = 'https://homepage.com/home/page1/222.6 a_type-A/go'
pattern = r"(?<=page1/).*?(?=_type)"
replace_with = '222.6'

s = re.sub(pattern, replace_with, l)
print(s)
```

The pattern uses the [positive lookahead and lookback assertions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), `?<=` and `?=`. A match only occurs if a string is preceded and followed by the assertions in the pattern, but does not consume them. Meaning that `re.sub` looks for a string with `page1/` in front and `_type` behind it, but only replaces the part in between.